# Particles.js not allowing spawn around text

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles

I've finally got particle.js working as a background.

But you can only spawn stars when you click above or below the text (height-wise) you cannot spawn them where the text is (or on the same line as it's container).

Is there a way to fix this?

My HTML:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- particles.js container -->
<div id="particles-js"></div>
<!-- particles.js container -->

<body>
 <div class="something">
  <h1> MY TITLE </h1>
 </div>
</body>

<!-- particles.js library -->
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
```

My CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p { margin: 1em auto;}

canvas {
  display: block;
}


#particles-js {
 width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 1%, #0c0c24 100%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -50;
}

.something {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.something h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 10em;
}
```

My JS:

```
particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 160,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 1,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": true,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 4,
        "size_min": 0.3,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": false,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 1,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": true,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 600
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 250,
        "size": 0,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 0,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 400,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});
```

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/nhtnmpx0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the fix.

You need to add the interactivity on the `window` as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/) or define your own `canvas` to make it working

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhtnmpx0/1/)

```
"interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "window",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
```

Comment: Worked amazingly, I was struggling to make repulse work, default it was detect_on : canvas, and due to z-index and multiple layers on canvas, it wasn't working. Once I changed to window, its working awesome, Thanks a lot